# T-SQL List Tables, Columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

In T-SQL (SQL Server 2000).   How can I list all tables and columns in a database?
Also, in a separate query is there a way to list all columns along with data type and constraints (NULLS, etc).   Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views or `sysobjects`, `syscolumns` etc.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Please check out the [information schema](http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/system-information-schema-views-transact-sql).

```
select *
from MyDatabaseName.information_schema.columns
order by table_name, ordinal_position
```

Comment: Thanks Tim I appreciate this.  Is there a way to add in what database the tables are assigned to? I see the Catalog is master.

Comment: `use MyDatabaseName;`, then query. [MSDN: Selecting a Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180770.aspx). Alternatively, add the DB name to your `from` clause in normal [4-part fashion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177563.aspx) (I've added this to the answer).

Comment: I had just found that.  Thanks again

Answer (score 16):

Many ways to do it. Below are couple of ways that you can list :

**Option 1:**

```
SELECT db_name() as DATABASE_NAME, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, ORDINAL_POSITION,
       COLUMN_DEFAULT, DATA_TYPE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH,
       NUMERIC_PRECISION, NUMERIC_PRECISION_RADIX, NUMERIC_SCALE,
       DATETIME_PRECISION
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

**Option 2:**

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(8000)
SELECT  @SQL = ''
SELECT  @SQL = @SQL + 'UNION
SELECT ''' + name + ''' [DataBaseName], t.name [TableName], c.name [ColumnName], st.name [DataType] FROM ' + name + '..sysobjects t INNER JOIN ' + name + '..syscolumns c ON t.id = c.id INNER JOIN '+ name + '..systypes st on c.xtype = st.xtype where t.xtype = ''U'''
FROM master..sysdatabases
WHERE name IN ('databasename1', 'databaseName2')  -- change here !!
SELECT @SQL = RIGHT(@SQL, LEN(@SQL)-5) + ' ORDER BY 1, 2, 3'
EXEC(@SQL)
```

**Option 3:**

```
select db_name() as database_name
    ,table_name = sysobjects.name
    ,column_name = syscolumns.name
    ,datatype = systypes.name
    ,length = syscolumns.length
from sysobjects
inner join syscolumns on sysobjects.id = syscolumns.id
inner join systypes on syscolumns.xtype = systypes.xtype
where sysobjects.xtype = 'U'
order by sysobjects.name
    ,syscolumns.colid
```