# SQL Server query to get the list of columns in a table along with Data types, length, unique, not null, primary key, foreign key and it's reference

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a query to to get the list of columns in a table along with Data types, length, not null, unique, primary key, foreign key and it's reference.

I use the below answer with MySQL, but I need it in SQL Server.

[Showing MYSQL table columns with key types and reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30720609/showing-mysql-table-columns-with-key-types-and-reference)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL server query to get the list of columns in a table along with Data types, NOT NULL, and PRIMARY KEY constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418527/sql-server-query-to-get-the-list-of-columns-in-a-table-along-with-data-types-no)

Comment: thanks @Dale Burrell but it doesn't include foreign key and it's reference

Comment: There are plenty of suitable built in queries - a quick Google found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573301/t-sql-list-tables-columns) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887370/sql-server-extract-table-meta-data-description-fields-and-their-data-types)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need something like this. If you want to see only tables with foreign keys you need to change `LEFT JOIN` to `INNER JOIN`.

```
SELECT    t.object_id
        , t.name TableName
        , C.name ColumnName
        , C.column_id ColumnSeq
        , S.name DataType
        , tf.name ParentTableName
        , CF.name ParentColumnName
FROM sys.tables T
INNER JOIN sys.columns C ON T.object_id = C.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.types S ON C.system_type_id = S.system_type_id
LEFT JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns FSK ON FSK.parent_object_id = t.object_id  AND FSK.parent_column_id = C.column_id
LEFT JOIN SYS.columns CF ON FSK.referenced_object_id = CF.object_id AND FSK.referenced_column_id = CF.column_id
LEFT JOIN SYS.tables TF ON cf.object_id = TF.object_id
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for

```
SELECT C.name ColumnName,
       OBJECT_NAME(C.object_id) TableName,
       OBJECT_NAME(FKC.referenced_object_id) ReferencedTable,
       COL_NAME(FKC.referenced_object_id, FKC.parent_column_id) ReferencedColumn,
       T.name DataType,
       C.max_length,
       C.precision,
       C.collation_name,
       C.is_nullable
       --...
FROM Sys.Columns C LEFT JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns FKC
         ON C.object_id = FKC.parent_object_id
     JOIN Sys.Types T
         ON C.system_type_id = T.system_type_id
WHERE C.object_id = OBJECT_ID('YourTableNameHere');
```